# Next js 13.4 how to disable page reload when I change tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I do not understand why my page reloads every time i exit and come back to my browser. For example, i have a form, and i need to copy and paste some content, but i lose the form inputs as the page reloads by itself. Not sure where the form is coming from.

I've tried:

```
export const dynamic = 'force-static';
export const revalidate = false;
```

Comment: It seems your component will render. You can store your inputs with useContext